# Does $(x+1)^p \equiv x^p+1 \pmod {p^3} \iff x^3 \equiv 1 \pmod p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm attempting to work out a solution to [Are there any solutions to the following congruences where $t^3 \not\equiv 1 \pmod {p^3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4284334/are-there-any-solutions-to-the-following-congruences-where-t3-not-equiv-1-pm)

For $1 < x < p-1$, the following surprising conjecture seems to hold for primes $p<5000$:

$$(x+1)^p \equiv x^p+1 \pmod {p^3} \implies x^3 \equiv 1 \pmod p$$

I think I have a lengthy demonstration of the converse, but haven't found a way to show this direction. Any ideas or suggestions would be great!

[Show that $(x+1)^p \equiv x^p +1 \pmod{p^2}$ given conditions on $x$ and $p$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4128454/show-that-x1p-equiv-xp-1-pmodp2-given-conditions-on-x-and-p/4157421#4157421) is another very similar problem.

Comment: note that if x is a solution, the following are all solutions:
$$x, \frac{1}{x},-(x+1),-\frac{1}{x+1},-\frac{x}{x+1},-\frac{x+1}{x}$$